# Selecting previous or next row with condition on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, common-table-expression, mysql-8.0

Here is my schema, MYSQL 8.0 is used:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `GameID` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `EventNumber` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CommandID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventNumber`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `events` (`GameID`, `EventNumber`, `CommandID`,`Timestamp`) VALUES
('1414485','23','228','2021-02-27 18:10:17.594000'),
('1414485','26','228','2021-02-27 18:10:21.294000'),
('1414485','28','1054','2021-02-27 18:10:22.803000'),
('1414485','30','228','2021-02-27 18:10:25.248000'),
('1414485','39','2078','2021-02-27 18:10:36.409000'),
('1414485','41','228','2021-02-27 18:11:44.306000'),
('1414485','44','1054','2021-02-27 18:11:46.926000');
```

[The result is as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZSIg.png)

| GameID | EventNumber | CommandID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1414485 | 23 | 228 | 2021-02-27 18:10:18 |
| 1414485 | 26 | 228 | 2021-02-27 18:10:21 |
| 1414485 | 28 | 1054 | 2021-02-27 18:10:23 |
| 1414485 | 30 | 228 | 2021-02-27 18:10:25 |
| 1414485 | 39 | 2078 | 2021-02-27 18:10:36 |
| 1414485 | 41 | 228 | 2021-02-27 18:11:44 |
| 1414485 | 44 | 1054 | 2021-02-27 18:11:47 |

- The **gameid** is the id of a game that commands are being sent, so
  it will be static for this example.
- Eventnumber is row number for the record for the specific game. e.g. 23 means, that '228' command is
  sent as 23rd command
- CommandID is the ID of the command. 228 means 'free-kick pop up generated', 1054 means 'free-kick confirmed home team' and 2078 means 'free-kick confirmed away team'
- Timestamp is when the command is sent.

The goal is to find how much time we spend on the pop-up. The problem is that not always a pop-up is followed by a confirmation. As you can see, EventNumber is not incrementing 1by1, which means other commands are sent in between but filtered with the query.

I tried following query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *
   FROM events ev
  WHERE ev.GameID = 1414485 -- #filter for the actual table 
    AND ev.CommandID in(1054, 228, 2078) -- #filter for the actual table
   ORDER BY ev.Timestamp
)
SELECT LAG(cte.CommandID) OVER(ORDER BY cte.EventNumber) AS PreviousEvent,
       LAG(cte.Timestamp) OVER(ORDER BY cte.EventNumber) AS PreviousEventTimeCode,
       cte.CommandID AS CurrentEvent,
       cte.Timestamp AS CurrentEventTimeCode,
       cte.Timestamp - LAG(cte.Timestamp) OVER(ORDER BY cte.EventNumber) AS TimeDifference
  FROM cte
 WHERE cte.commandID in (1054, 2078);
```

As ultimately, the confirmation needs a pop-up, I wanted to filter out the commands and want to have the previous 228 and its timestamp. However, with the last line, it, unfortunately, filters all the 228 commands, therefore lag could not get the previous 228.

| PreviousEvent | PreviousEventTimeCode | TimeDifference | CurrentEvent | CurrentEventTimeCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 1054 | 2021-02-27 18:10:23 |
| 1054 | 2021-02-27 18:10:23 | 13 | 2078 | 2021-02-27 18:10:36 |
| 2078 | 2021-02-27 18:10:36 | 111 | 1054 | 2021-02-27 18:11:47 |

I could not figure out the problem and ended up here.

Thanks in advance!!

Edit:
[Here is the target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLmDX.png)

| GameID | PreviousEvent | PreviousEventTimeCode | CurrentEvent | CurrentEventTimeCode | TimeDifference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1414485 | 228 | 2021-02-27 18:10:21 | 1054 | 2021-02-27 18:10:23 | 2 |
| 1414485 | 228 | 2021-02-27 18:10:25 | 2078 | 2021-02-27 18:10:36 | 11 |
| 1414485 | 228 | 2021-02-27 18:11:44 | 1054 | 2021-02-27 18:11:47 | 3 |

DB Fiddle Link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hNtRKMQasz3NuJgcSwiD38/0#

Comment: Incidentally, the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost entirely meaningless, and probably best omitted.

Comment: added the DB fiddle link, and a desired outcome screenshot.

Comment: tables are added

Answer (score 0):

Number pairs of events starting from most recent one.

```
with cte as (
   select ev.* 
      , row_number() over(partition by case when ev.CommandID=228 then 1 else 2 end order by EventNumber desc ) rn
   from events ev
   where ev.GameID=1414485
      and ev.CommandID in (1054,228,2078)
)
select GameID, min(CommandId) PreviousEvent, min(timestamp) PreviousEventTimeCode
  , max(CommandId) CurrentEvent, max(timestamp) CurrentEventTimeCode
  , max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) TimeDifference
from cte
group by rn
having min(EventNumber) != max(EventNumber)
order by rn desc
```

The query builds on starting `CommandID` < ending `CommandID`. Otherwise encode start / end with a `case` used in the `partiton` expression.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d2d2e404f59a4d5778c2069e964f383)

Comment: Hi Serg, that was quite good approach, and i really appreciate it. I had to partition over the GameID as well as there are many gameid with concurrent times. 
I sorted the problem with 2 CTE's. I will compare the performance and pick up the best one.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CanerBas, logically those queries are not equivalent. Consider adding an event `('1414485','29','1054','2021-02-27 18:10:23.000000')`

Answer (score 0):

Your version is quite close.  This does what you want:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by gameid order by eventnumber) as prev_timestamp,
             lag(commandid) over (partition by gameid order by eventnumber) as prev_commandid
      from events e
      where commandid in (228, 1054, 2078)
     ) e
where commandid in (1054, 2078);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=669fa2b9c16685d11f4a8f9a45a22baf) is a db<>fiddle.

The only significant difference between this and your code is the filtering for the `lag()`.  Here the `lag()` is in the subquery, so it is working on all three events.

In your version, the filtering is in the outer query so event 228 is not considered for the `lag()` -- the `lag()` runs (conceptually) after the rows are filtered.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this also helped. Both approaches took almost equal time (for a month data which is around 200k rows) 15 seconds. I used nested queries for my initial solution and that is doubling the calculation time  (almost 31 seconds).

 I will check one of them. All in all, it is a good practise for lag and lead which was a bit complicated for me. Cheers

Comment: @CanerBas . . . 15 seconds on 200k rows of data seems pretty slow.  You must be on a slow machine or have a poorly configured server.

Comment: I have unfortunately no control over the DB and its configuration. I may try to optimize the code, thanks for letting me know